# speed up video using avconv without quality loss

Tags: video, libav

After having read [this page](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video), I'm using avconv (which in this case is apparently same as ffmpeg, and which I need to use instead since I'm on Ubuntu trusty) to speed up a .swf video.

I don't want a quality loss (not interested in compression), just a visual speed-up.

```
avconv -i input.swf -filter:v "setpts=0.5*PTS" output.swf
```

results in quality loss. how do I prevent that?

I don't see why this occurs, `mplayer -af scaletempo -speed 1.7 myvideo.swf` plays it fine.

---

From reading [this page](http://libav.org/avconv.html) I tried

```
avconv -i input.mkv -filter:v "setpts=0.5*PTS" -b 1080 output.mkv
```

But it didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Gotcha!

```
avconv -i HTSA2-copy.swf -filter:v "setpts=0.5*PTS" -b 12000k -s 1080x1080 Sped_up-setpts=0.5*PTS-HTSA2.swf
```

the `-b` and `-s` parameter values might be overkill haha, but it gets me what I wanted.

Comment: Unless your video is actually square, you should probably make it `-s 1920x1080`

Comment: yes, square it was!

Answer (score 2):

its can be tricky if you also want to scale audio too, for example you want to make it 10% slower (110 or 1.1)

*for audio its 1/1.1=0.90909..

```
avconv -i input.webm -c copy -map 0:0 v.webm
avconv -i input.webm -c copy -map 0:1 a.webm
avconv -i a.webm -acodec libmp3lame a.mp3
avconv -i v.webm -vf setpts=1.1*PTS v2.webm
sox a.mp3 a2.mp3 speed 0.90909
avconv -i a2.mp3 a2.webm
avconv -i a2.webm -i v2.webm -c copy output.webm
```